# В sql server на основе данных одной таблицы создать новую каждый день в определённое время

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, select

Подскажите как создать новую таблицу с данными из первой таблицы. И чтобы новая таблица создавалась каждый день в определённое время?

Comment: *как создать новую таблицу с данными из первой таблицы.* `CREATE TABLE tablename (table specification) SELECT ..`. *чтобы новая таблица создавалась каждый день в определённое время* `dbo.sp_add_job`

Comment: Создавать новую таблицу каждый день это вообще плохая идея

Comment: не проще в таблицу добавить поле с текущей датой / таймстемпом, создать по ней индекс, и сделать вьюху/хранимую процедуру которая будет выбирать данные через запрос вида select * from my_table where mydate = getdate() ?